# None Values or Missing Data

Tags: categorical-data, missing-data, ordinal-data, data-preprocessing

Suppose I have a feature "Pool Size" whose levels are: Big, Medium, Small.

Surely if a house doesn't have a pool it certainly won't have a value for "Pool Size".

Q1-For this particular instance/house, should I consider the value for "Pool Size" missing ('NA') or should I makeup a new category for 'Pool Size' dedicated to houses that do not have a pool size lets call it 'None' or 'NoSize'?

Q2-If I choose to makeup a new category for 'Pool Size' then my feature would become categorical instead of ordinal. Wouldn't that be a problem as I am essentially changing the nature of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get this information, it would be good to include it into the dataset. Your proposal to add a value `none` to the size feature sounds okay, after all, no pool is still smaller than a small pool. However, if you  want to keep the feature ordinal as it is, you could add a new binary feature `has pool` to indicate this information.

Comment: When you said "no pool is still smaller than a small pool" this helped me understand that it's ok to let 0 values if pool size was a numerical feature or a value of 'None' if pool size was a categorical feature (as presented in my example). This makes sense. However, I don't think your strategy of adding a flag feature 'has pool' would help in keeping the feature ordinal. At least, I don't see how. Perhaps you could expand on that further